# $ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{C_i}\text{ is weakly compact} $

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. Let $C_1,...,C_n$  are nonempty weakly compact convex subsets of $X$. Why

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{C_i}\text{ is weakly compact}
$$
An idea please.

Comment: Consider the “average” map: $X^n \rightarrow X$. It is continuous wrt the norm topologies and linear, so is continuous for the weak topologies. Now, your set is the image of $C_1 \times \ldots \times C_n$. To conclude, just see that the weak topology on $X^n$ is the product of the weak topologies on each $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for a topological vector space $X$ and compact subsets $A$ and $B$, $A+B$ is the image of the compact set $A\times B$ under the continuous map $+: X\times X\rightarrow X$. Hence $A+B$ is compact. Multiplication by scalars also preserves compactness.